# Regular Expressions for replacing strings that have one tag type in Javascript 

Tags: javascript, html, regex, tags

I want to replace all strings between, before and after `<span style="[^"]+">.*?</span>` tags that may be in string with span tags **(no other HTML tags, just simple text)**
I have regular expression like this.

```
var span_re = /^(.+)(?=<span)|(?=<\/span>)(.+)(?=<span)|(?=<\/span>)(.+)$/g;
str = str.replace(span_re, '<span>$1</span>');
```

for this string

```
'foo<span style="text-decoration:underline;">bar</span>baz'
```

I got

```
'<span>foo</span><span style="text-decoration:underline;">bar<span></span>'
```

I want this:

```
'<span>foo</span><span style="text-decoration:underline;">bar</span><span>baz</span>'
```

I also try using: `.+?`, `.*?` and instead `.+` capturing whole expression with no result.

**I don't need a parser I don't parse XHTML and don't have self-contained tags.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) ...please just use an HTML parser already :(

Comment: I don't want to parse XHTML I have only one tag type (span) and text before, between, after - why use something that complicated as a parser for this simple substitution, I line of code instead of ~1k for a parser.

Comment: @MattBall Yes, one should use a parser. Be that as it may: here’s the [obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4231382/471272); please link to actual answers, not to non-answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing HTML using regex is seldom a good idea, particularity in the context of a web browser. Here's a simple example that gets what you want, using jQuery:

Even if that HTML isn't already inside the DOM, it is easy to wrap it in a dummy element:

```
var wrapper = $('<div />')
wrapper.html('foo<span style="text-decoration:underline;">bar</span>baz');
wrapper.contents()
  .filter(
      function(){return this.nodeType == 3;} //select text nodes only
   ) 
  .wrap('<span />');
```

As a bonus, that will work well with other tags, and even if you have several `<span>` tags with free text *between* them.

Working example: **http://jsbin.com/acigu5/**

Comment: Thanks for answer but I already find solution for this - span tags was created by me when I substitute formating strings like this `[[uib;color;background]text]` for span tags (with basic style) so instead of use replace first I split the string and get text between formating strings and don't need to match tags.

Answer (score 1):

You may be over complicating it. If you know you only may have a single `<span>`, no other tags and no unescaped `>` signs, you can use this simple regex:

```
s = s.replace(/^[^<]+|[^>]+$/gi, '<span>$&</span>');
```

This regex finds text before the tag (from the beginning, not `<`) or after the tag (not `>`, until the end), and wraps them with a `<span>`. `$&` in JavaScript regex replace stands for the whole match, or group 0 (on other flavors that may be `\0` or `$0`).

Note that `(?=<\/span>)` from your original regex is a look-ahead, not a look-behind (JavaScript doesn't have look-behind. shame). That caused `(.+)` to match the closing tag and consume it, resulting in invalid HTML.

Working example: **http://jsbin.com/acexu4/**

Comment: Thank for this but I don't have one tag, but one tag type - so they may be meny of them but not nested. And good to know that JavaScript don't have look-behind for future usage.